# Centering the axis title between two concatenated Altair plots

Tags: python, altair, vega

I have an Altair plot that is a vertical concatenation of subplots. However, they share the y-axis *title*, and I would like to place this in the middle of the two plots.

For example, let's say I have this:

```py
from sklearn.datasets import load_iris
import altair as alt
import pandas as pd

iris = load_iris()
_, y = load_iris(return_X_y = True)
df = pd.DataFrame(iris.data, columns=iris.feature_names).assign(label=y)

chart_a = alt.Chart(
    df[df.label == 0]
).mark_point().encode(
    x='sepal length (cm)',
    y='sepal width (cm)',
)
chart_b = alt.Chart(
    df[df.label == 1]
).mark_point().encode(
    x='sepal length (cm)',
    y='sepal width (cm)',
)

result = (chart_a & chart_b)
```

I'm not using faceting here because in my real example the scales are quite different. I have also annotated where I would like the shared y-axis label to be:

[image].

I'm also hoping to remove the y-axis label from each of the subplots, but I think that's easier to do.

How can I implement this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just an FYI, you can still facet and have independent scales. Faceting makes it easier than concatenating charts together in this case. i.e.

```
import altair as alt
from vega_datasets import data

iris = data.iris()



alt.Chart(iris).mark_point().encode(
    alt.X('petalLength:Q'),
    alt.Y('petalWidth:Q', axis=alt.Axis(title=''))
).properties(
    width=180,
    height=180
).facet(
    row=alt.Row(field=alt.Field('species'),type='nominal',header=alt.Header( title='Sepal Width (cm)', labels=False, titleFontSize=25, titleColor='red'))
).resolve_scale(
    y='independent',
    x='independent',
)
```

[image]

Comment: Both my x and y scales need to be different. Is that still doable?

Comment: Yes. I will update the answer to show this.

Comment: Unfortunately this doesn't quite work for my real example which is two heatmaps where the top and bottom heatmaps share some columns but not others. However that's on me for not making a better example, and you've answered my question as I asked it very well.